# Element fading in the direction of css animation during translation

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I am making a game in which the user controls a ball as per his input. But the problem is that the ball while translating its position from point A to point B is fading during the animation in the direction of motion.

I have also attached a basic snippet which illustrates the problem.

Please have a look.

```js
var item = document.getElementById('item');
var anim;
var x=0, y=0;
function myMoveLeft(){
 anim=item.animate([
  { transform: `translate(${x}px, ${y}px)` }, 
  { transform: `translate(${x-100}px, ${y}px)` }
], {
     duration: 500,
     iterations: 1,
     fill: 'forwards'
  });
}

function myMoveDown(){
 anim=item.animate([
  { transform: `translate(${x}px, ${y}px)` }, 
  { transform: `translate(${x}px, ${y+150}px)` }
], {
     duration: 600,
     iterations: 1,
     fill: 'forwards'
  });
}
```

```css
button{
  display:inline-block;
  height:40px;
  width:80px;
}
#myContainer {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  background: DarkSeaGreen ;
}

#item {
  background: darkgreen;
  position: absolute;
  right:30px;
  top:30px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  margin: 0px;
  border-radius:50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1.0, 1.0);
  transform: translateZ(0) scale(1.0, 1.0);
  filter: blur(0);
  


}
```

```html
<p>
  <button onclick="myMoveLeft()">Left</button> 
<button  onclick="myMoveDown()">Down</button> 
</p>

<div id ="myContainer">
  <div id="item"></div>
</div>
```

As can be seen, some part of the circle is being eaten away during rendering. I did try some troubleshooting by adding scale transforms and other css solution present in the snippet, but none works for me.

PS: I have made enough progress with my application to change the .animation() technique. If possible, kindly suggest if something can be done to get around this "bug".

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

u can use `transition: all ease 1s;`

```js
var item = document.getElementById('item');
var anim;
var x=0, y=0;
function myMoveLeft(){
 item .style.right = '130px'
}

function myMoveDown(){
  item .style.top = '90px'
}
```

```css
button{
  display:inline-block;
  height:40px;
  width:80px;
}
#myContainer {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  background: DarkSeaGreen ;
}

#item {
  background: darkgreen;
  position: absolute;
  right:30px;
  top:30px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  margin: 0px;
  border-radius:50%;
  transition: all ease 1s;
  filter: blur(0);
}
```

```html
<p>
  <button onclick="myMoveLeft()">Left</button> 
<button  onclick="myMoveDown()">Down</button> 
</p>

<div id ="myContainer">
  <div id="item"></div>
</div>
```